# How can I get an array in a dict? Python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm wondering how I can print out an array in a dictonary in Python.
This is my dict:

```
  {
        "type": "NonStockItem",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeId": "string",
            "description": "string",
            "sortOrder": 0,
            "required": true,
            "attributeType": "Text",
            "defaultValue": "string",
            "details": [
              {
                "id": "string",
                "description": "string"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "id": "string",
        "description": "string"
      }
```

I'm trying to get out the attributes field

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    itemClass = json.loads(response.text)
    
    for itemClass in itemClass:
        print(str(itemClass["type"]))
```

What am I missing?

Expected output: current output just lists out all the types. Expected output is

```
{
    "type": "NonStockItem",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attributeId": "string",
        "attributeId" : "string".
        "attributeId" : "string",
        
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: this line makes no sense: `for itemClass in itemClass:`
maybe do something like `for item in itemClass: print(item)` to get an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: I didn't understand how the code you have shown relates to your question. Have you tried `the_dict['attributes']` if `the_dict` is the dictionary you have shown at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Well, with a dict you can just call the dict with the key that you want and it will return your data just like this:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    itemClass = json.loads(response.text)
    print(itemClass["attributes"])
```

(Or any other key in your dict)

Comment: Lets say I want the attributeId field in attributes, how do I get that?

Comment: @SuzdarIbrahim `print(itemClass["attributes"]["attributeId"])`